# Computer turns off unexpectedly (new battery)

Tags: windows, laptop, battery

Recently I purchased a new battery online from newegg. Upon using it I noticed some strange symptoms:

-Computer randomly turns off before battery is anywhere near low level

-Once the computer shuts-down like above, it will not turn back on, unless charger is put in for at least a few seconds. (I can take it back out once it turns on without complications)

-After turning back on, Windows says the battery still has high charge level

-This does not happen when the charger is plugged in.

**Additional information:**

-I am running windows 10 technical preview. -*I haven't heard anything about the preview of windows having trouble with batteries. Additionally battery operations seem like a lower level thing*

-I am running an overclock on the computer -*This overclock had been calibrated into a stable state for over a year*

-This is not an overheat issue -*I monitor system temperature with Core Temp 1.0 RC1*

-More information can be released upon request

---

**Is my battery defective and how can I tell?**

Comment: Is it an OEM battery or after-market?

Comment: I don't think it is from the original equipment manufacturer. When I bought it said it was compatible with my laptop, but not the exact model. (ex: battery is for dv6, dv7, dv...; laptop model is dv6 61203 bleh bleh bleh....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your battery is not specifically meant for that model, that could help explain why it might be causing this issue.

Also, since your computer doesn't have this problem when the charger is plugged in, and because the computer will turn on if the charger is plugged in, but will not if it isn't, then this is almost a guarantee that your battery is at fault, since it's not an OEM battery. I agree with the other responders: try going back and having it replaced... if they refuse a refund, you might need to purchase another one.

However, if the new battery, specifically for your model, does not work either, there is a problem with how your laptop handles battery input/output. In this scenario, you might need a new system, or put up with it being always plugged in (I have mine always plugged in as I have a docking station up 24/7.)

Comment: The battery said it was for my model series (but not specifically) so I'm going to just claim my warranty. I think it's more likely it is defective than misleading info on the manufacturer's part.

Answer (score 1):

If is it not an OEM battery, that may explain the odd behavior. Many manufacturers are making it more difficult to use an after-market battery. Try going back to the seller and replacing it. You will soon know if it is unusual.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what question you are asking.

I do point out that most laptop batteries have logic built into the battery.  It sounds like the battery is faulty - but I doubt anyone would be able to say if its the cells or the logic on the battery - although If I think about it if 1 of the cells in the battery is stuffed it could produced a problem like the one you are describing - as it is draining power from the other batteries.

It is remotely possible that the Laptop has been calibrated to require certain minimum and maximum voltage values and the battery is working OK, but with different parameters and sending advice that the laptop is interpreting incorrectly.

Comment: Do you think it would be a good idea to return the battery for another?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Then I tried Linux Ubuntu 18. I made a USB stick with the ISO and used the option to try out Ubuntu without installing it. I have had 2 hours watching YouTube before the battery warning of 9% remaining popped up.

To me this is a strong indication it is something within Windows that causes the unexpected shut down. Why else would Linux happily be running so long if the battery would be wrong/old/worn?

Tonight I will wipe the disk and reinstall Windows 10. If it happens again, I will try Win7.

Comment: I resolved this issue years ago by purchasing another battery. The one I received was likely defective. Software was not the issue for me.